# How can I query multiple tables relationship in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this table with multiple table relationships

```
class _FoodsInStock(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'FoodsInStock'

    date = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    breakfasts = relationship('_BreakfastsInStock')
    lunch = relationship('_LunchInStock')
    snacks = relationship('_SnacksInStock')
    cereals = relationship('_CerealsInStock')
    fruits = relationship('_FruitsInStock')
    cookies = relationship('_CookiesInStock')
    chocolates = relationship('_ChocolatesInStock')
    others = relationship('_OtherFoodsInStock')
```

I am trying to get a specific table that is related to the `_FoodsInStock` table

I know I can do something as simple as this:

```
table = _FoodInStock.query.get(id).breakfasts
```

That works perfectly but I need to get the table related depending on some input, and doing that would take me to write that line per line

Is there any way of doing something to have the tables related depending of an input?
something like in a dictionary:

```
tables = ['breakfasts', 'lunch', 'snacks', 'cereals', 'fruits', 'cookies', 'chocolates', 'others']

for table in tables:

    q = _FoodInStock.query.get(id)[table]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these are attributes, you should be able to achieve this with `getattr`:

```
tables = ['breakfasts', 'lunch', 'snacks', 'cereals', 'fruits', 'cookies', 'chocolates', 'others']

for table in tables:
    q = getattr(_FoodInStock.query.get(id), table)
```

Comment: Great - if it's working please accept the answer (and optionally upvote it).